# Native Box Appear and Disappear

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am facing a problem again. I am using native box to add text like user name in my profile scene code. 
But the problem is if i change the scene, native box stay in its place. I have tried these methods:

1. I have made name input box global and manually add and delete it. It
   do delete but when i come again on profile scene it is still
   deleted. ( it doesnt reappear ).
2. I have made name input box
   global and manually add and delete it through enterScene and
   exitScene, but these functions just do nothing. ( native box appear
   in other scenes too ).
3. I have made name input box global and
   manually add and delete it through showScene and hideScene, but
   these functions just do nothing. ( native box appear in other scenes
   too ).

What to do? Please Help.

Below is my code.

Comment: Hey, you forgot to add the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Corona SDK API call that starts with native. cannot be managed by scene managers like Storyboard and Composer.  You cannot add them to the scene's view group. You should create the native.newTextField() or native.newTextBox() in the scene's enterScene (Storyboard) or scene:show() (Composer) event functions. Then you should manually remove them in the scene's exitScene (Storyboard) or scene:hide() (Composer) functions.

Native objects always sit on top of the Corona OpenGL canvas that the rest of the display system runs in.  This cannot be changed, it's just the way Corona works.